# How to make d3js node positions deterministic?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am trying to use http://nylen.tv/d3-process-map/graph.php but every time I refresh the page, the position of the nodes with group changes. How can I prevent this? I want the position of nodes with a group to not change on page refresh.

Comment: I shouldn't have to open a link to understand your question. One day your external link will stop working, and in all probability it will be before the death of SO. When that happens will this question make any sense at all? Will it be useful to anyone else who encounters the same problems as you? If the answer to these questions is "no", then it's a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc :

> If you do not initialize the positions manually, the force layout will initialize them randomly, resulting in somewhat unpredictable behavior.

So you have to setup the initial positions of your nodes to obtain a non random graph